# Spark - Update a nested column to string

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
 |-- x: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- y: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- z: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- aa: string (nullable = true)
```

I have the above nested schema where I want to change column z from struct to string.

```
 |-- x: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- y: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- z: string (nullable = true)
```

I'm not using Spark 3 but Spark 2.4.x. Will prefer Scala way but python works too since this is a one time manual thing to backfill some past data.

Is there a way to do this with some udf or any other way?

I know it's easy to do this via to_json but the nested array of struct is causing issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cast as in higher order function

```
df3=df.withColumn('x', expr('transform(x, s-> struct(s.y as y,cast(to_json(s.z) as string) as z))')).printSchema()

root
 |-- x: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- y: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- z: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Doesn't work - I get `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'named_struct(NamePlaceholder(), namedlambdavariable() due to data type mismatch: Only foldable string expressions are allowed to appear at odd position, got: NamePlaceholder; line 1 pos 25`

Comment: Instead of `s.y` you should use `s.y as y`

Comment: @ZygD That seems to have worked but it removes the key aa from the stringified version of the struct. Any way to have the key in the string as well?

Comment: Hah doing cast(to_json(s.z) as string) seems to keep the key as well.

Comment: wwnde thanks for the great solution - I edited it a bit. Also, similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72037029/update-a-highly-nested-column-from-string-to-struct - I'm trying to use your logic for that as well but I'm not sure how to pass in schema for for_json to work inside expr/transform. Any suggestions? Can you take a look at that question too? 

Also thanks @ZygD

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/functions/from_json - used this as a reference it works for the other question too!

Comment: @Chirag Sejpal, sorry was at work. answered, could you please let me know if that helps. Happy to assist further

Answer (score 1):

For your specific case, you can do it with built-in functions on Spark 2.4 or Spark 3.0

#### Spark 2.4

You can use [`arrays_zip`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#arrays_zip(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) as follows:

- first, you create arrays for each field you want to have as struct element of your array
- second, you use `arrays_zip` to zip those fields

Here is the complete code, with `df` your input dataframe:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.functions.{arrays_zip, col}

df.withColumn("x",
      arrays_zip(
        col("x").getField("y").alias("y"),
        col("x").getField("z").getField("aa").alias("z")
      ))
```

#### Spark 3.0

You can use [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#transform(column:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,f:(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,org.apache.spark.sql.Column)=%3Eorg.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) to rebuild element struct of your array, as follows:

```scala
df.withColumn("x", transform(
      col("x"),
      element => struct(
        element.getField("y").alias("y"),
        element.getField("z").getField("aa").alias("z")
      )
    ))
```

Comment: I'm looking to stringify the struct as opposed to getting aa out of z.